# How to separate polygon and point legends in map ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a map that includes many shapefiles and I'm having trouble with the legend. This is the map as is but I'd like the polygons to also be in the legend.
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJvp7.png)

This is the code I'm using (as I'm using multiple shapefiles I have no idea how to make this reproducible, sorry about that):

```
ggplot(data = transformed_sea)+
  geom_sf(fill="lightblue1")+
  geom_sf(data = transformed_locations, size = 2, aes(color = Fjord, fill = Fjord))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Dark2")+
  geom_sf(data = transformed_places, size = 2, color="black", fill="black")+
  geom_sf(data = halseborder, size = 2, color = "tomato", fill = "tan1", alpha = 0.2, show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_sf(data = ff1, size=2, color = "deeppink4", fill = "deeppink", alpha = 0.4, lwd=1, show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_sf(data = ff2, size=2, color = "purple3", fill = "mediumpurple1", alpha = 0.4, lwd=1, show.legend = TRUE)+
  geom_sf(data = vad, color = "tomato", fill = "tan1", alpha = 0.2)+
  geom_sf_text(data = transformed_labels, aes(label = ID), size = 3, color="grey34") + 
  geom_sf_label_repel(inherit.aes = FALSE, data=transformed_places, aes(label = ID),force = 10, nudge_x = 2.5, seed = 1, size = 3) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(636224.5703011239, 674153.32093384),ylim = c(6421546.462142282, 6472000.544186506))+
  xlab("Longitude")+ ylab("Latitude")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(11.3, 11.6, 11.9),
                     labels = c("11.3°E", "11.6°E", "11.9°E")) +
  annotation_scale(location = "bl", width_hint = 0.3)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_rect(fill = "papayawhip"))
```

As you can see I've added the argument `show.legend=TRUE` in the lines mapping the polygons but it just causes it to overlap the fjord legend like so:
[map with bad legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcvAJ.png)

Does any one know of a way to have separated legends, with one showing the fjord points and the other the different zones (halseborder,ff1 and ff2)?